# How to run Parallel function from joblib with multi arguments without cross function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, joblib

I am trying to use multiple arguments using Parallel function in joblib. I am not sure but it is doing cross-function mechanism with these arguments

lets say I have two lists [1,2] and [5,7] when I multiply to lists I want 5,14 as my output.

```
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np

def my_function(myList, parameters):
    print(myList*parameters)


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
inputs = [1,2]
parameters = [5,7]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(my_function)(myList= i,parameters = j) for i in inputs for j in parameters)
```

the above code seems to output 5,7,10,14, but I want 5,14 which is 1 x 5,2 x 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import multiprocessing
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np

def my_function(myList, parameters):
    print(myList*parameters)


num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()



inputs = ((2,3),(3,5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    processed_list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(my_function)( i, j) for i,j  in inputs )
```

I figured it out that I need to use tuples